# Eclipse does not launch my program, but no errors

Tags: java, eclipse

Here is my source Code: 
**The main class:**

```
package daPackage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

class apples{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Gui go = new Gui();
        setUpGUI(go);
    }

    private static void setUpGUI(Gui g){
        g.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        g.setVisible(true);
        g.setSize(375, 175);
    }
}
```

Here is my second class:

```
package daPackage;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.EventListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Gui extends JFrame{
    private JButton button;
    private JTextField field1;
    private JTextField field2;
    private JTextField field3;
    private int num1;
    private int num2;
    private int num3;

public Gui(){
    super("Testing!");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    field1 = new JTextField("" + num1);
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(field2.getText()) + Integer.parseInt(field3.getText()); 
    add(field1);

    field2 = new JTextField("" + num2);
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(field1.getText()) + Integer.parseInt(field3.getText());
    add(field2);

    field3 = new JTextField("" + num3);
    num3 = Integer.parseInt(field1.getText()) + Integer.parseInt(field2.getText());
    add(field3);

    button = new JButton();
    button.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                field1.setText("" + num1);
                field2.setText("" + num2);
                field3.setText("" + num3);
            }
        }
    );
    add(button);    
}


}
```

Eclipse says that there is no errors, but when I click the *Run-button* nothing happens. I have checked my code several times, but I can't find the problem.

Comment: Refresh your project once.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Gui.<init>(Gui.java:21)
    at apples.main(apples.java:5)
```

That is, in the line:

```
num1 = Integer.parseInt(field2.getText()) + Integer.parseInt(field3.getText());
```

`field2` is still null (also `field3`).

Answer (score 0):

Declare **Public** in the main Class

You are getting Null Pointer Exception because,You are using field1 and field2 without initializing it.

intialize first and then use it.

Do like this in your **Gui** class

```
class Gui extends JFrame{
    private JButton button;
    private JTextField field1;
    private JTextField field2;
    private JTextField field3;
    private int num1=0;
    private int num2=0;
    private int num3=0;

public Gui(){
    super("Testing!");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    field1 = new JTextField("" + num1);
    field2 = new JTextField("" + num2);
    field3 = new JTextField("" + num3);
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(field2.getText()) + Integer.parseInt(field3.getText()); 
    add(field1);


    num2 = Integer.parseInt(field1.getText()) + Integer.parseInt(field3.getText());
    add(field2);


    num3 = Integer.parseInt(field1.getText()) + Integer.parseInt(field2.getText());
    add(field3);

    button = new JButton();
    button.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                field1.setText("" + num1);
                field2.setText("" + num2);
                field3.setText("" + num3);
            }
        }
    );
    add(button);    
}
}
```

And your apples class

```
 public class apples{
        public static void main(String args[]){
            Gui go = new Gui();
            setUpGUI(go);
        }

        private static void setUpGUI(Gui g){
            g.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            g.setVisible(true);
            g.setSize(375, 175);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks all! 
It works fine now!
- Well, it looks lige crap, i need some layouting.

Answer (score 0):

I've compiled your code, And I got those errors :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at daPackage.Gui.<init>(Gui.java:24)
at daPackage.Main.main(Main.java:7)
Java Result: 1
```